# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ a factorization domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Is easy to prove that this is not a UFD, since $6 = 2 \cdot 3 = (1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$ where $2, 3, (1+\sqrt{-5}), (1-\sqrt{-5})$ are irreducible and are not associate to each other.

I'm not sure how to prove that every $a \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has a factorization. The best thing I could think of is that, since every number has norm greater or equal than $1$, and $|ab| \geq |a|$ for every $a$, then the process should end at some time.

Answer (score 3):

Your observation, the fact that units are precisely the elements with norm 1, and that the ring is Noetherian is enough to conclude it is a factorization domain.